# How to trigger a journey is wishlist items are discounted or changed in price

Tags: marketing-cloud, trigger

So our client has the idea to trigger a journey that if a subscriber has items in their wishlist, and one or more of these items have decreased in price, then we want to trigger a journey for this subscriber with an email that their wishlist product is a better buy at the moment.

Can this be done by using the behavioral trigger of the abandoned wishlist, or can this be achieved in a another way?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can build the logic in your external system and fire an Event API trigger journey via rest API https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/postEvent.html

Answer (score 0):

You can save the item price along with the SKU id in the wishlist, along with the Contact Key. You can query these wishlist records, comparing the saved price along with the price from your current catalogue. In case the price in the catalogue is lower than the one in the wishlist, you can add the combination of SKU ID and Contact Key into a sendable DE, triggering an email. All this can be achieved in Automation Studio